# .animate not working with .mouseenter/leave event?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div as follows.

html:

```
<div id="leftdock"></div>
```

css:

```
#leftdock
{
    position: absolute;
    float:left;
    height: 400px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    background-color: #BADA7F;
    top: 30%;
}
```

following javascripts using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#leftdock').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).animate({
        margin-left: "-25px"
        }, 500);
    });

    $('#leftdock').mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).animate({
        margin-left: "-25px"
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

But with this the animation does not work. My div margin-left is not changing with mouseenter/leave even.

Comment: Is it normal that the margin-left value is the same for both function()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an error in the console it should be "margin-left" in quotes and 25px instead of -25px.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XpFJX/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#leftdock').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).animate({
        "margin-left": "25px"
        }, 500);
    });

    $('#leftdock').mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).animate({
        "margin-left": "-25px"
        }, 500);
    });
});
```